# Calculating a Range of Binomial Probabilities.

Tags: probability, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

**Question:** The probability of a letter sent through mail correctly making it to its intended destination is $0.95$. What is the probability that, for $30$ letters, at least $20$, but no more than $25$ make it through?

**Attempts:** If we suppose that the probability of an event happening is given by $p$ and we want the probability that the in a trial of $n$ runs, the event happens at least $x$ times, but no more than $y$ times, I know that this can be calculated with the sum $\displaystyle \sum_{k=x}^{y} {}^{n}C_{k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$, however I am looking for a way to be able to compute this question without having a sum like this as this is quite painful to compute.

Comment: Well, I understand your wish to not have a sum in the expression ... But in my opinion,
$$
\sum_{k=20}^{25} {30 \choose k} 0.95^{k} 0.05^{30-k}
$$
is not that difficult to enter into the calculator ...

Comment: Yeah, in this case it's easy to compute, but say it was 200 to 250 out of 300. I'm looking for an easier way to compute something like that.

Comment: First of all, I upvoted - interesting question, nicely presented, good work shown.  I don't think that there is an easy answer.  What I would do: (1) Letting $f(k)$ represent $\binom{n}{k}p^k~q^{(n-k)}$, create a recursive formula that calculates $f(k+1)$ based on $f(k)$. (2) write a computer program (i.e. in Java, C, or whatever language you are comfortable with) to compute $\sum_x^y f(k)$.  Note that although my first instinct is to involve logarithms, given that you are **summing** individual terms, I don't think that logarithms buys you anything. ...see next comment.

Comment: With a large number of letters, perhaps one could use the Central limit theorem ...

Comment: One possible exception.  Suppose that (for example) you wanted to compute $\sum_{(20)}^{(25)} f(k)$.  You could **construe** $f(20)$ as a **common factor** of all terms.  Under those circumstances, it might be helpful to use logarithms (only with respect to the common factor).